# sharing my page URL on twitter via twitter share button

Tags: asp.net, twitter

I have a problem using twitter share button on my asp.net page.The problem is that when I click on the share button i want it to share the URL of my page which the share button exists for example "***http://localhost:1349/Pages/Share/ShareRedeemtion.aspx?UID=2&GiftID=1&MID=2 via@QhatAPP***" but for some reason which i can't figure the button only share the title of the page, I'm confused is there is a problem with twitter share button to share URLs which contains a query string? and if do exists a problem is there any way enables me to share my URL on twitter via twitter share button?

Comment: What does your code look like for the button? Seeing that would help.

Comment: <a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?URL=http://localhost:1349/Pages/Share/ShareRedeemtion.aspx?UID=2&GiftID=1&MID=2"  class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical" data-via="Islamnosser">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have 2 problems:

1. You need to encode the URL you are passing in because, yes, it has a querystring on it. Check out [URLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) if you need to.
2. It also doesn't appear to work with non-publicly accessible Urls (your localhost in the sample).  It may be doing some sort of callback to check that the Url is accessible or checking for Spam.

A sample that works with a querystring.

```
https://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F8190644%2Fsharing-my-page-url-on-twitter-via-twitter-share-button%3Ftemp%3D1&text=Test+Link
```

For more information and properties for the button, check https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button